# Which is the better solution for getting all elements in an li

Tags: jquery, dom, getelementsbyclassname

Of these two methods does the second option provide a better/faster solution.

```
$(goods).parent().parent().children().eq(1).children().eq(1).children();
```

1st option: My function passes in an element "goods", which I then transverse the dom to get to to the li that contains my elements

```
var b = document.getElementsbyClassname();
```

2nd option is to simple grab the elements in need by their class names.

It's not specifically required for this project to support anything below ie 9 but we would like to try, which would disqualify the 2nd option but my question is: Is there any significant difference between these two option that would make the 2nd "worth" the loss of ie support?

Comment: in jquery also if you `$('.className')` It will get all the elements with that specific classaname.And can you post the relevent `HTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first option is a **severe** performance hit on the user's browser as it will traverse the DOM tree in the opposite direction.

Your second option can be written in jQuery, hence you won't loose IE support.

Write your jQuery like

```
var allElementsWithClass = $('.className');
```

You can then loop over the result.